# Change ownership of Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to make a layout creator, where one can drag a widget from a gallery onto a screen. To do this I've made made two components - `LayoutWidgets` and `LayoutCanvas`. Both these components have [vue-grid-layouts](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) as children.
My idea is that when dragging an item from the gallery to the canvas, the item component would be re-parented to the canvas layout (this is approaching it from a raw JS perspective, where `.appendChild` can be used to rearrange the DOM), while still staying in its dragging state and retaining event listeners etc.
does Vue's VDom have any way of doing this?
Here is my current wrapper component:

```html
<template>
    <ResizablePanes class="resizer-root">
        <LayoutCanvas ref="canvas"
                      style="flex-grow:2"
                      @dragging="dragEvent($event, 'canvas')"/>
        <LayoutWidgets ref="widgets"
                       style="flex-grow:1"
                       @dragging="dragEvent($event, 'widgets')"/>
    </ResizablePanes>
</template>
<script>
import LayoutCanvas from './LayoutCanvas.vue';
import LayoutWidgets from './LayoutWidgets.vue';
import ResizablePanes from './ResizablePanes.vue';
export default {
    components: {
        LayoutCanvas,
        LayoutWidgets,
        ResizablePanes,
    },
    data: () => ({
        dragging: null,
        dragParent: null,
        dragReceiverRefs: ['canvas', 'widgets'],
    }),
    computed: {
        dragReceivers() {
            return this.dragReceiverRefs
                .filter(x => x != this.dragParent)
                .map(x => ({
                    grid:this.$refs[x].$refs.grid,
                    bBox:this.$refs[x].$refs.grid.$el.getBoundingClientRect()
                }))
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dragEvent(item, ref) {
            if (!item) {
                this.dragging = null;
                this.dragParent = null;
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.dragHover);
            } else {
                this.dragging = item;
                this.dragParent = ref;
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.dragHover);
            }
        },
        dragHover(e) {
            const receiver = this.dragReceivers.find(x => 
                x.bBox.left <= e.clientX &&
                x.bBox.top <= e.clientY &&
                x.bBox.right >= e.clientX &&
                x.bBox.bottom >= e.clientY
            );
            // need help here:
            receiver.grid.appendChild(this.dragging);
            //
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check out how I rearrange the dom using an array of vue components here. https://github.com/tomshaw/linkmate/blob/master/src/options/App.vue My personal web site is dynamic using the same technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, This was an unnecessarily difficult problem but I've managed to create a solution, that I'll post here if anyone in the future ever finds this.

Note that in this code:

- `moveNode` is the Vue Component to move
- `oldGrandParent` is the ancestor of this parent that contains its `prop` definitions
- `newGrandParent` is the equivalent ancestor this it is getting moved to
- `newParent` is the immediate parent Vue Component that will hold it

```js
// New data object
const newLayout = { x:0, y:0, w:moveNode.w * 2, h:moveNode.h, i:Date.now() };
// Remove VNode from old parent
const vNode = moveNode.$parent._vnode.children.splice(moveNode.$parent._vnode.children.indexOf(moveNode.$vnode), 1)[0];
// Rekey it
vNode.key = newLayout.i;
// Move HTMLElement
newParent._vnode.elm.appendChild(vNode.elm);
// Move VNode
newParent._vnode.children.push(vNode);
// Clean up old parent
moveNode.eventBus.$emit('dragEvent', 'dragend')
// Re-initialise Node for new parent (using copied source code - I don't think there's an easier way to do this)
this.rebindEventBus(moveNode,  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(newParent, "eventBus"));
// Continue cleaning up old parent
moveNode.$parent.$children.splice(moveNode.$parent.$children.indexOf(moveNode), 1)
oldGrandParent.layout.splice(oldGrandParent.layout.findIndex(x => x.i == moveNode.i), 1);
// Give Vue instance new parent
moveNode.$parent = newParent;
// Add new data object to new parent, triggering reactivity
newGrandParent.layout.push(newLayout);
// Call Nodes "mounted" hook to finish re-parenting
this.$nextTick(function() { moveNode.$options.mounted.slice().reverse()[0].call(moveNode); });
// Reparenting complete!
```